# optimise Yii2 MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, yii2

I need to optimise my code.it works but takes time and sometimes timeouts.

Objective selected columns from table 1 and table 2 must be combined in another table. duplicates are not allowed in the new table.  TIA

```
 $modelsc=Customers::find()->select('customer_id')->all();
 $modelsp = Product::find()->select('product_no')->all();
 foreach($modelsc as $modelc) {                                                                      
     $user = $connection->createCommand(
           'SELECT product_no as product_no,:cust_no as fkcustomer_id                                                                                                         
             FROM product AS p                                                                                                           
             WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT pc.fkproduct_no                                                                                                                         
             FROM                                                                                                                               
             productcustomer AS pc
             WHERE
            pc.fkproduct_no = p.Product_no AND fkcustomer_id = :cust_no)');
      $user->bindValue(':cust_no', $modelc->customer_id);
      $modelsx = $user->queryAll();    
      Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('productcustomer', [ 'fkproduct_no', 'fkcustomer_id'], $modelsx)->execute();                                                          }
```

Comment: Please provide you tables schema.

Answer (score 0):

looking to your code you could avoid the not exists clause an try using a left join checkn for null on pc.fkproduct_no

```
SELECT product_no as product_no,
      :cust_no as fkcustomer_id                                           
FROM product AS p   
LEFT JOIN  productcustomer AS pc ON  pc.fkproduct_no = p.Product_no 
    AND fkcustomer_id = :cust_no  
WHERE pc.fkproduct_no  is null
```

Anyway be sure you have proper index on the column where of join condition

for table `products`  an index  on column `Product_no`

for table  `productcustomer` a composite index on `(fkcustomer_id, fkproduct_no)`